# Function call skips the function's statement

Tags: c, string, function-call

whenever I call this function it skips over the fgets statement inside it.

```
void getString(char *str){ /* Read a string from the keyboard */
    fprintf(stdout,"Please enter a string: ");
    fgets(str,MAX_STRING_LEN,stdin);
}
```

here's the function call

```
if(strcmp(cmd,"new")==0){ /* new string command */
        getString(current);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it has been called? What "current" is? You think it's not called because of debugger (inlining?) or because it doesn't output anything?

Comment: @haccks I believe you meant output? Flushing `stdin` is UB.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves; Oops! Deleting my comment :)

Comment: current is actually a string array;

Comment: command is accepting "new" because it displays the fprintf statement but glosses over the fgets statement. immediately prompts for new command

Comment: @leovic: If it displays the output from the `fprintf` statement, then at least one statement within `getString` *isn't* being skipped.  Edit your question to more accuracy describe what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, but as the question is right now, all we can do is to just speculate. Please consider providing everything relevant (and even possibly relevant) so that we can give an *answer*. Here, another speculation: Could you possibly have a redirected standard input `stdin` in your hands? Either through an `freopen` call, or by doing something that I don't know on Linux terminal thing...

Comment: @leovic you really need to actually post a program that shows the behaviour instead of just 2 statements that don't have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably mixing use of scanf() elsewhere in your program and fgets().  Use fgets() for all your input, always to a string, than if necessary use sscanf() to convert the string into other data types.

See the comp.lang.c FAQ which describes this in further detail:

http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html

Answer (score 0):

The output of the fprintf(3) is buffered.  You need to flush that buffer to force out the prompt before trying to read the input.  The `stderr` channel is usually unbuffered so you could write to that without flushing manually.